# AES crypto used in SaltStack

Tags: aes

Does anybody know where I can find infos on cryto used in saltstack. I know it's AES but can't find info on key size (128/256/... ) and if it's possible to configure?

The source code seems to reference AES 128, 1024 key size, HMAC-SHA256 and AES-CBC but as I'm not fluent with python and it's not clear to me if and how I can do AES256.

Comment: The crypto within saltstack seems to differ between versions. Please indicate which version and try and link to a document describing the protocol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about finding information on a piece of software, and although this information is about cryptographic aspects, the question in itself is not about the cryptography.